# jQuery - Pass variable to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I'm very new to this and I've searched around all day today to get it working but I haven't managed to find a way to use a variable, only hard-coded values work. Here is my code with a hard-coded value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
      $.post("http://www.my-domain.com/fbtest.php", { category: "845" } );
      }
  );
</script>
```

What I'd like to have is change that 845 value to a variable called $vpostid. When I change it to that it doesn't work, so I assume I need to get the double quotation marks around the number but I can't see to get the correct combination.

Comment: well where are you getting vpostid from?

Comment: I'm getting that from this $vpostid = $post->ID; which I have echoed out and it gives me the correct post id each time on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm **assuming** you mean "pass variable *from* php":

If short hand openings are enabled:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
      $.post("http://www.my-domain.com/fbtest.php", { category: "<?=$vpostid?>" } );
      }
  );
</script>
```

else:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
      $.post("http://www.my-domain.com/fbtest.php", { category: "<?php echo $vpostid; ?>" } );
      }
  );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
      $.post("http://www.my-domain.com/fbtest.php", { category: "<?php echo($vpostid); ?>" } );
      }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you both for the replies (including @h2ooooooo), I have tried the two ways both with and without the parenthesis but it still doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm going something wrong in my fbtest.php page?

`<?php
/** Set up WordPress environment */
require_once('./wp-load.php');
$vcatid = $_POST["category"];
$meta_val = get_post_meta($vcatid, 'fb_likes', true);
$fbmetval = intval($meta_val);
$fbmetval = fbmetval + 1;
update_post_meta($vcatid, 'fb_likes', $fbmetval);
?>`